# Как при переходе на страницу обновить модель?

Tags: angularjs

Вопрос по ангуляру 1.6.9 с подключённым роутингом. Имеется "дерево" элементов. И на одной из страниц имеем код вроде такого:

```
<a href="/#!/elements/{{ element.id }}/list">{{ element.name }}</a>
```

Нам необходимо, что бы при переходе по этой ссылке менялась модель (обновлялось свойство). Например, если изменить его вот так:

```
<a ng-click="element.name='hello world'">{{ element.name }}</a>
```

То имя модель обновляется - мы добились необходимого поведения, но правда по ссылке не переходит - что не годится.
Какой есть выход из сложившийся ситуации? Спасибо заранее :)

Comment: `ng-click="$ctrl.updateNameAndRouteTransition(element)"`

Comment: @norbornen, если указан атрибут `href`, то ng-click не выполняется(

Comment: я имел ввиду, что нужно написать функцию, которая и `element.name` изменит, и переход сделает

Comment: пытаюсь сделать директиву, но не понимаю как через неё обновить модель, не подскажите? )

Comment: ну я хз что за задачу ты решаешь и правильными ли инструментами. если ты делаешь директиву (что давно не модно) то там есть двунаправленное связывание, если компоненту - можно передавать функцию, которую вызывать при клике и в ней менять модель

Comment: @norbornen, делаю аналог проводника в windows, слева дерево, справа элементы. При переходе в окне справа дерево тоже должно открываться